# cannot delete record which hasMany relationship to same record type (ember data 1.0.0-beta.9)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I recently upgraded from ember data 1.0.0-beta.2 to ember data 1.0.0-beta.9. There is a piece of code to delete a record that works perfectly fine in beta 2, but it doesn't work in beta.9

My model looks like this:

```
AS.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    questionName: DS.attr('string'),
    childQuestions: DS.hasMany('question', {
        async: true
    })
});
```

And my delete method looks like this:

```
deleteQuestion: function (question) {
    var self = this;
    question.deleteRecord();
    question.save().then(function () {
        console.log('success');
        //unload child records from the store because server removes all the child questions
    }, function (failureResponse) {
        console.log(failureResponse); 
        console.log('failure');
        //perform rollback
    })['finally'](function () {
        console.log('in finally');
    });
}
```

In ember data beta 9, it never goes through the success function if my question has child questions, it always goes to the second function that catches failure. The delete only works if a question does not have child questions. I also tried deleting all child questions first before deleting a parent question model but still it goes directly to failure block. 
The delete request however resolves correctly with http status 200 and the response from the delete request is an empty object {}.

The "failureResponse" it coughs out is :

```
    Error: Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object
    at new Error (native)
    at Error.EmberError (lib/ember/ember.js:13538:33)
    at Object.Ember.assert (lib/ember/ember.js:3722:27)
    at set (lib/ember/ember.js:16834:23)
    at Ember.Object.extend.hasManyDidChange (lib/ember/ember-data.js:7112:11)
    at null.<anonymous> (lib/ember/ember-data.js:7101:18)
    at lib/ember/ember.js:14897:34
    at Object.OrderedSet.forEach (lib/ember/ember.js:14739:28)
    at Object.Map.forEach (lib/ember/ember.js:14895:26)
    at Ember.Object.extend.reloadHasManys (lib/ember/ember-data.js:7098:23)
```

It must have been caused by :

```
  hasManyDidChange: function(key) {
    var hasMany = this._relationships[key];

    if (hasMany) {
      var records = this._data[key] || [];

      set(hasMany, 'content', Ember.A(records));//ONE OF THESE SETS IN EMBER-DATA 
      set(hasMany, 'isLoaded', true);
      hasMany.trigger('didLoad');
    }
  },
```

Any idea how can I make my delete work in this beta release? Also if you know how to quickly create a fake server then I could probably create a jsbin for it - I tried using sinon but couldn't make things work.

Regards,
Dee

**UPDATE:**
This issue must be caused by something else, since I couldn't recreate this issue here : http://jsbin.com/yofuqa/2/
But still its weird that the same logic would work in beta 2 but not in beta 9!

With beta .11, the hasMany relation do not even load. Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/yofuqa/3/